# Print again the last printed paper using command line

Tags: command-line, printing

The scenario :

I want to print again the last  printed paper in my printer... Is't possible... I've came to some commands such as `lpstat`, `lpr` , `lp` but can't find if such option is really exist.

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: You could look up `lpstat -W completed` to get the job id of completed jobs, then run `lp -i <job id> -H restart` to restart it, assuming cups still has the file in its spool.

Comment: What muru said +in CUPS webinterface (http://localhost:631) you can configure that your printed documents are stored after completion.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes I do,

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your cups webinterface [localhost:631](http://localhost:631/admin/?ADVANCEDSETTINGS=YES) and check this:

   Note this:

   - `1d` = Maximum age of a job
   - `500` = Maximum number of saved jobs

   depending on what occurs at first

   [image]
2. Now you can restart the latest job with this command in a terminal:

   ```
   lpstat -W completed | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} lp -i {} -H restart
   ```

   shorter

   ```
   lpstat -W completed | head -n1 | awk '{system ("lp -i "$1" -H restart"}'
   ```

   compact

   ```
   lpstat -W completed | awk 'NR>1{exit};{system ("lp -i "$1" -H restart")}'
   ```

Comment: Note though that it is possible you no longer have  the print job in the spool anywhere so this may not work.

Comment: @ThomasW. thx and done